# SemanticImport unable to properly read an Excel file with accented letters

Tags: dataset

Apparently `SemanticImport` fails to properly import Excel files when accented letters are present in the first (header) row. I'm using Excel 2013 on Windows 8.1 x64 with Mathematica 10.0.2.

I tried different most obvious `CharacterEncoding` options without success.

Is this a bug?

Or does exists a proper option to use?

Answer (score 1):

I'm actually using the following workaround, based on `Import` and manual construction of the `Dataset` expression. This also allow me to specifiy in the header row an optional unit for each column (as a string in parenthesis at the end of the column name).

```
data = Import[
   "Preliminary Reference Earth Model (PREM).xlsx", {"Data", 1}, 
   Path -> NotebookDirectory[]];
keys = StringReplace[#, " (" ~~ x__ ~~ ")" ~~ EndOfString :> ""] & /@ 
   data[[1]];
units = StringCases[#, " (" ~~ x__ ~~ ")" ~~ EndOfString :> x] & /@ 
   data[[1]];
units = Map[Quantity[None, #] &, units, {2}] /. {} -> 1 // Flatten;
Dataset[AssociationThread[
     keys, #] & /@ ((Rest[data]\[Transpose]*units)\[Transpose])]
```

From this file:

[image: Excel file]

I get this `Dataset` (not perfect, fist column should be an `Integer`):

[image: Mathematica graphics]

while with `SemanticImport` the column `"LaméFirstParameter"` becomes `"LamÃÂ©FirstParameter"`:

[image: Mathematica graphics]